# How to connect with SQL Server database using .NET Core Class Library (.NET Standard)?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2017

I have just started to create an ASP.NET Core Web API Project. I am not much aware of "ASP.NET Core .NET Standard Library".

I am creating this application using Visual Studio 2017 RC and in the application, I have taken a project of type Class Library (.NET Standard) at repository layer.

Following is the screenshot for the same:

[image]

Now from repository Layer I want to connect to the database. I have created a variable

```
IDbConnection con;
```

Now I am trying to add reference of ***System.Data*** but I am unable to add any reference because when I am opening the add reference window then I am getting the following message:

> *No Framework assemblies were found on the machine.*

How can I connect to database using .NET Core Class Library(.NET Standard)?

[image]

Comment: Use Entity framework

Comment: Class library isn't related in any ways to ASP.NET Core!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

.NET Standard Class libraries don't work by directly referencing a DLL, because with .NET Core there is no guarantee the framework will be installed on the system and .NET Core applications can also run as self-contained applications which ship the framework libraries with the application and do not require a runtime to be installed before.

You have to use the NuGet package manager (or project.json or *.csproj in VS2017) to add dependencies. For SQLServer you need to add the `System.Data.SqlClient` package ([link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/)) if you want to directly communicate with the Database (i.e. w/o an ORM).

Answer (score -1):

Above answer (Tseng) may have been valid in 2016 and .NET Standard 1.4, but in the meantime, Microsoft did remove some showstoppers, allowing access to SQL Server from a .NET Standard 2.1 library. Mind the old `System.Data.SqlClient` will not link, so you (really!) have to refer EF6 via NuGet and change some using.

- Create a .NET Standard Class library and put version on 2.1
- Install Entity framework (this contains the lower level libs)
- In using, refer to `System.Data` **and** to `Microsoft.Data`

Using are:

```
using System.Data
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

Now, "legacy" classes like `DataSet`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlClient` will become available.

It is not completely compatible (yet) There are some things that are not available in .NET standard 2.1, such as enumerating available SQL servers on the LAN. This was done with `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` which is a class in `System.Data` I cannot locate in `Microsoft.Data`.

NOTE: I tested successfully with a .Net Core 3.1 console application. A Standard lib configured as above can be called from .NET Core and connect to the database without issues. You *cannot* use a .NET Framework caller.