# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection not found - namespace has only a couple of classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, .net-standard

I am trying to create an SQL connection in a UWP app but the namespace System.Data.SqlClient only has two classes available (to do with client permission)

I have added NuGet package System.Data.SqlClient / Common and the namespace is available but incomplete

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

…


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

The SqlConnection class cannot currently be found so I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the relevant references but to no avail. The Target Framework is .Net Standard 2.0 with the Min version set as Fall Creators Update

Is there another reference that I am missing or does another NuGet package need installing?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app

Comment: Are you using Entity connection for the database or Data.SqlClient?  The Nuget is probably using Entity which requires a data mapping between the database and ted c# classes. The incomplete is indicating an issue with the Entity mapping.

Answer (score 2):

First check the project.json, *.csproj or Dependencies for be sure references are add currectly (from nuget: current version is System.Data.SqlClient (4.6.1) .Net Framework) then add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` in a class from the project and create an SqlConnection instance.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            new SqlConnection().ConnectionString = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Please see this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315727/how-to-connect-with-sql-server-database-using-net-core-class-library-net-stan).